# HTML To PDF Converter - Html2PDF - how to reduce the size of the result PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, large-files

I am using HTML2PDF converter in order to export web page to PDF file. The issue I have faced is that the result PDF is to large (more than 1 MB). I want to reduce it, so here is what I have basically:

1. 2 images (100 KB both)
2. 1 Courier Bulgarian font - added
3. 3 tables with a lot of inline styles of each cell

Could these things lead to the large size of the output PDF? And could anyone share some experience and best practices with the library in order to get smaller PDF as result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what those three tables contains? are they used to display some repetitive data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mananged to find what causes the big size of my output PDFs files. It last the fonts.

For my task I have used courier bulgarian (italics, normal and bold). This means I have embeded three additional fonts.

Something more, I do not know, but helvica is the defauld font for this PHP library and althought I am not using it, it is embeded to the PDFs too.

If you meet the same issue, open all files that have "helvica" and replace the "helvica" font with this that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Adobe Acrobat, it'll let you peek in the PDF and see which areas use what percentage of space. This would tell you how much of the space is taken up by images, fonts etc... If you make a sample PDF available I'll be happy to take a look at it.

How much space in the PDF is used by different objects really depends on how the PDF was written and how efficiently it uses different compression algorithms. For example, images can be ZIP, JPEG or even JPEG-2000 compressed in PDF, the question is what HTML2PDF does with your images.

Fonts can be big as well - depending on what the size of the original font is.

Page content (your tables with inline styles etc) are written in a condensed textual format (for example `1 0 0 rg` would be the instruction to set the fill color for text and line-art to red). Normally efficient PDF writers will write all of these textual instructions and then ZIP compress them, which means they won't take much place in the file.

So you'd really need to take a look at the PDF file itself to see where the space is used. That will allow you to start looking at the library to see if it can be made more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To start with...

- Have one separate page for printing and displaying - for printing.
- While printing use Ptint.CSS and include as less as possible classes
- In those three tables.  Keep only require classes in CSS.  Please use compress images  for printing e.g if you have BMP in display use the PNG for printing.
- Make tables simple using TR-TD and make them less colorfull do not put inline CSS.

This may help you to save PDF in compress version.